# Pandas Sklearn Pipeline - CV on DataMapper transforms?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I'm wondering how best to define parameters for datamapper transforms in a pipeline using pandas-sklearn.

[Here](https://github.com/andrewm4894/random/blob/master/pandas_sklearn_pipelines_titanic.ipynb) is a reproducible example notebook using titanic data.

I'm setting it up as:

```
# use pandas sklearn to do some preprocessing
full_mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    ('Name', Pipeline([ ('name_vect', CountVectorizer()) , ('name_tfidf', TfidfTransformer()) ]) ),
    ('Ticket', Pipeline([ ('ticket_vect', CountVectorizer()) , ('ticket_tfidf', TfidfTransformer()) ]) ),
    ('Sex', LabelBinarizer()),
    (['Age', 'Fare'], None), # i tried to use Impute() but got an error
    ])
```

I'd like to also cross validate the params in the CountVectorizer() and TfidfTransformer() that i'm using on the 'Name' and 'Ticket' fields.

However in defining my pipeline as:

```
# build full pipeline
full_pipeline  = Pipeline([
    ('mapper',full_mapper),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(n_iter=15, warm_start=True))
])
```

And then my params as:

```
# determine full param search space (need to get the params for the mapper parts in here somehow)
full_params = {'clf__alpha': [1e-2,1e-3,1e-4],
                   'clf__loss':['modified_huber','hinge'],
                   'clf__penalty':['l2','l1']}
```

I'm not sure how to include in the above options to go to 'name_vect', 'name_tfidf' etc.

I could not really find an example similar to what i'm trying to do here in the pandas-sklearn [docs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/sklearn-pandas).

Note: just using the titanic data here for reproducibility. Really just trying to get the plumbing working here.

**UPDATE** (trying to adapt approach from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/677/struggling-to-integrate-sklearn-and-pandas-in-simple-kaggle-task).)

If i do:

```
# make pipeline for individual variables
name_to_tfidf = Pipeline([ ('name_vect', CountVectorizer()) , ('name_tfidf', TfidfTransformer()) ])
ticket_to_tfidf = Pipeline([ ('ticket_vect', CountVectorizer()) , ('ticket_tfidf', TfidfTransformer()) ])

# data frame mapper
full_mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    ('Name', name_to_tfidf ),
    ('Ticket', ticket_to_tfidf ),
    ('Sex', LabelBinarizer()),
    (['Age', 'Fare'], None), # i tried to use Impute() but got an error
    ])

# build full pipeline
full_pipeline  = Pipeline([
    ('mapper',full_mapper),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(n_iter=15, warm_start=True))
])

# determine full param search space
full_params = {'clf__alpha': [1e-2,1e-3,1e-4],
               'clf__loss':['modified_huber','hinge'],
               'clf__penalty':['l2','l1'],
               # now set the params for the datamapper part of the pipeline
               'mapper__features':[[
                   ('Name',deepcopy(name_to_tfidf).set_params(name_vect__analyzer = 'char_wb')), # How can i set up a list for searching in here
                   ('Ticket',deepcopy(ticket_to_tfidf).set_params(ticket_vect__analyzer = 'char')) # How can i set up a list for searching in here
               ]]
              }

# set up grid search
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(full_pipeline, full_params, n_jobs=-1)

# do the fit
gs_clf.fit(df,df['Survived'])

print("Best score: %0.3f" % gs_clf.best_score_)
print("Best parameters set:")
best_parameters = gs_clf.best_estimator_.get_params()
for param_name in sorted(full_params.keys()):
    print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

Then i get:

```
> Best score: 0.746 Best parameters set:    clf__alpha: 0.01    clf__loss:
> 'modified_huber'  clf__penalty: 'l1'  mapper__features: [('Name',
> Pipeline(memory=None,
>      steps=[('name_vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
>         dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
>         lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
>         ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
>         strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
>         tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)), ('name_tfidf', TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False,
> use_idf=True))])), ('Ticket', Pipeline(memory=None,
>      steps=[('ticket_vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
>         dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
>         lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
>         ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
>         strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
>         tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)), ('ticket_tfidf', TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False,
> use_idf=True))]))]
```

So it looks like i am able to set the params here. However if i pass a list in like:

```
# determine full param search space (need to get the params for the mapper parts in here somehow)
full_params = {'clf__alpha': [1e-2,1e-3,1e-4],
               'clf__loss':['modified_huber','hinge'],
               'clf__penalty':['l2','l1'],
               # now set the params for the datamapper part of the pipeline
               'mapper__features':[[
                   ('Name',deepcopy(name_to_tfidf).set_params(name_vect__analyzer = ['char', 'char_wb'])),
                   ('Ticket',deepcopy(ticket_to_tfidf).set_params(ticket_vect__analyzer = ['char', 'char_wb']))
               ]]
              }
```

I get error such as:

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in build_analyzer(self=CountVectorizer(analyzer=['char', 'char_wb'], bi...)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None))
    265             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
    266                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    267 
    268         else:
    269             raise ValueError('%s is not a valid tokenization scheme/analyzer' %
--> 270                              self.analyzer)
        self.analyzer = ['char', 'char_wb']
    271 
    272     def _validate_vocabulary(self):
    273         vocabulary = self.vocabulary
    274         if vocabulary is not None:

ValueError: ['char', 'char_wb'] is not a valid tokenization scheme/analyzer
```

So unsure how to set the params of DataFrameMapper transfomations to options for the CV to search over.

Surely there must be a way. Agree though at this stage might be better to go pandas > numpy > FeatureUnion...

Comment: I'm afraid thats not an easily available task. Only thing I could find was this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/677/struggling-to-integrate-sklearn-and-pandas-in-simple-kaggle-task . I would recommend using FeatureUnion for this, not DataframeMapper.

Comment: cheers , yeah - i am going to dig into that question as seems like maybe it has what i need. Would love to just stay in pandas though as have been having all sorts of fun converting to numpy array with various different downstream errors when i do the CV for various different variable types. I'll adapt my approach to use something like df.to_records() to go to numpy array and then do feature unions. Have seen a few signs elsewhere that maybe pandas-sklearn not quite mature yet also.

Comment: Yes, it will prove to be of too much complexity to do what you want in the question. I am not sure of other parts of your code, but for the above problem FeatureUnion is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi Andrew, not sure if this will work, but you could try ticket_to_tfidf__*param_name* to set the nested parameters

Answer (score 1):

That's just one of the drawbacks I also experienced with the sklearn-pandas package.
However, I found that writing your own transformer classes gives you full control over what's happening in your pipelines and even in feature unions.

One can customize each sklearn transformer to select only certain pandas columns and even output then the transformation as pandas dataframe with some tweaks.

See my blog for a comprehensive tour:
https://wkirgsn.github.io/2018/02/15/pandas-pipelines/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note if you want to promote your own website or blog, **you must disclose your affiliation in the answer**. Otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I've edited that in for you this time. But please remember our policy towards potential self-promotion next time, and include the disclosure in your question/answer next time.